# Retrieve file POST to Laravel 5

Tags: forms, laravel-5, upload, postman

I'm trying to post a file to my upload function in Laravel. To keep things simple I'm using Postman to test it. According to the documentation, the way to access a file Request is:

```
$request->file('image')
```

so my controller function begins with :

```
  if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
     $file = $request->file('image');
  }
```

And my post request:

[image]

As you can see the parameter is NULL.

So what is the correct way to access a file post request in the controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = $request->hasFile('image'); 

if(isset($image)){
  //perform operation
}
```

The above should be what you need to check if there is a file in the request and then preform operations you want on the file.

Comment: hmmm... $image is now "false"

Comment: The only reason that would be happening is that there might be no file uploaded .

Comment: VikingCode before you say something is wrong be sure to have made your findings well.. and the request->hasFile() that you added was just added 3 hrs for a question answered more than 16 hrs , now let me educate you,  request->hasFile() checks if the a file is present in the request if there is no file it evaluates to false which is turn means that there is no file and isValid() cannot be called on null.

Comment: ok but if there is one ... what does it returns ? the file or just true ? ... so the value of $image would be true ... so what are you checking inside your if ? if image (true) is set ... <= that is why i sad your answer was wrong, to populate the variable with the file and not the obj, you need to use $request->file('image')

Comment: @VikingCode I dont know what documentation you are reading but go ahead and read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files I think that would enlighten you. best practices is to do a check first before you perform any operation.. and finally you cant call a method that on null.

Comment: @osleonard yes . now go back to your answer and watch your code again.